# How could I combine Swift and SignalR?

Tags: swift, signalr

So, I and a few other people are working a project where one part of the group is doing an Progressive Web App and the other part is doing an iOS app. Our back-end API is in .NET Core C#. We have decided to use SignalR so we can make the apps real-time. 
I have done a small research on SignalR and there is not much available information on how to use it with Swift. Could any of you give any recommendations/suggestions on how should I proceed and how I can combine Swift and SignalR?

Comment: You can use this library for implementing SignalR support on iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289819/how-could-i-combine-swift-and-signalr

Comment: That is a link to my question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Swift SignalR Client available for the ASP.Net Core version of SignalR. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift). This client allows you to connect to a SignalR server from your Swift application. Here’s a basic example of how you might set up a connection:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftSignalRClient

public class SignalRService {
private var connection: HubConnection

public init(url: URL) {
    connection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: url).withLogging(minLogLevel: .error).build()
    connection.on(method: "MessageReceived", callback: { (user: String, message: String) in
        do {
            self.handleMessage(message, from: user)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    })
    connection.start()
}

private func handleMessage(_ message: String, from user: String) {
    // Do something with the message.
}
}
```

I hope this helps!